# How to find if there is a common difference between integers in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, difference

Lets say that the users input is 7 10 12 14 16 20 25. I want the output to be a set of numbers in ascending order whose difference is all the same. So for this case it would be: 12,25,7,20 OR 10,14,16,20. Notice how in both cases their difference is the same and theres at least 4 numbers in the output. How do i do this?

I'm trying to find if there is a common difference between the integers in the array. I first thought that it would be better to sort them in ascending order and then if `sorted_array[1] - sorted_array[0] = sorted_array[2] - sorted_array[1]` then theres a common difference. But then it doesnt work if the numbers are for example `4 5 12 13 16 20 27 28` where theres a common difference between `[12,5], [20,13], [27,20]`

```
int r = 0; 
int l = 0; 
while (r < n) {
    if (arr_days4[r] - arr_days4[l] == arr_days4[r+1] - arr_days4[l+1]) {
        sequence_difference++;
        r++;
        i++;
    }
    else if(arr_days4[i] - arr_days4[r] > arr_days4[r + 1] - arr_days4[l+1]){
        l++;
    }
    else{
        r++;
    }
    printf("\n%d", sequence_difference);
}
```

When I try to print sequence_difference it gives me 32767...Can anyone help?

Comment: I suggest you should format your code properly.

Comment: yep, sorry about that

Comment: is the formatting still bad??

Comment: okay, do you know why im getting 32767 as the value for 'sequence_difference'?

Comment: How is `sequence_difference` declared and intialized?

Comment: sorry, thats meant to be sorted_difference, fixed it now

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://ideone.com/j38oAB). Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note that the `while` loop body won't be executed because `i < n` is granteed to be false by upper `for` loop, and that if initialization `i = 0;` is added just before the `while` loop, `sorted_array[r+1]` may become out-of-range.

Comment: okay, it should be fine now

Comment: Which platform (OS) do you observe this on? Also `32767` is `0x7fff`.

Comment: However, how would you expect us to explain the output if not specifing the input?

Comment: sorry, Lets say that the users input is 7 10 12 14 16 20 25. I want the output to be a set of numbers in ascending order whose difference is all the same. So for this case it would be: 12,25,7,20 OR 10,14,16,20. Notice how in both cases their difference is the same and theres at least 4 numbers in the output. How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should clear the requirement or specify the provided input and the output you want.
but seeing your code there's many mistakes i can figure out

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (array[i] > array[j]) {
            a = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = a;
        }
    }
}
```

the inner loop must iterate n-1 times because of at last pass i will exceed n if you don't do this.
next error is in your while loop you have used i which is having value n becuase of upper for loop.
so try to look at these mistakes.
for more info you [can check](http://ccodinggeek.blogspot.in/2016/03/c-program-to-implement-bubble-sort.html)

Comment: Okay sorry about that, ill fix that code in my program, thank you! Lets say that the users input is 7 10 12 14 16 20 25. I want the output to be a set of numbers in ascending order whose difference is all the same. So for this case it would be: 12,25,7,20 OR 10,14,16,20. Notice how in both cases their difference is the same. How do i do this?